# How much time is remaining?

Tags: code-golf, string, date

## The Program

You are given two strings, **A** and **B**. **A** is the current position at which your timer is at, and **B** is the position at which your timer will stop. Both strings are in the format **m:ss**. You must write a program that determines the amount of time left which should also be formatted as **m:ss** or **mm:ss**.

## Example

```
0:00 0:01 -> 0:01
0:55 1:00 -> 0:05
1:45 3:15 -> 1:30
```

Comment: In dc the input is read incorrectly, since `:` is a command (data as code philosophy). Am I allowed to use spaces instead or do I need to find other language to answer this?

Comment: is `01:30` valid output? (leading zero)

Comment: Yes, I'll accept that as valid. I'll edit the description.

Comment: @seshoumara The input must contain a colon.

Comment: What is the maximum value expected for **m**?

Comment: Maximum expected is 9. @DigitalTrauma

Comment: @obarakon, it is in format of minutes:seconds, not hours:minutes:seconds, so your solution isn't valid unfortunately.

Comment: Is the result guaranteed to be positive. so "3:15" "1:45"  is not considered valid input?

Comment: The result will always be positive

Answer (score 91, accepted):

## Excel, 6 Bytes

```
=B1-A1
```

Assuming A is in cell `A1` and B is in cell `B1`

Comment: No... NO... I WILL NOT LET EXCEL WIN. +1 you devious individual.

Comment: Cancel that, `|vy':¡` bootstrapped in 05AB1E, nothing I can do... I think Excel may honestly win this, nothing else automatically parses that format that I know of.

Comment: HOW? HOW? How is Excel winning? My brain must now explo...

Comment: If **m** is greater than 23, then the formatting doesn't seem to work.  For example if I type `45:45` in A1 and `22:22` in B1, then the result is `23:23:00` **Edit** Nevermind - max expected value for **m** is 9.

Comment: Someone file a feature request in 05AB1E.

Comment: This only works if you've formatted the cell with the formula, right? If it's formatted as "General" then the result is numeric by default and displays as a fraction of a day like `0.0625`.

Comment: @EngineerToast Whatever the default formatting is worked for me. I just typed in the input, moved to a different cell, typed the formula and hit enter.

Comment: Ah, that's because typing in something that looks like a time automatically changes the value. Typing `1:45` and exiting the cell changes the cell value to `1:45:00 AM`. Therefore, you're not sending strings into the function, you're sending time values. Try either prefixing the input with a backtick to force it as a string or formatting the cell to Text. That's when the formula as written spits out a numeric solution.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, if the cell is formatted as `[m]:ss`, then it would work up to 9999 minutes

Comment: Excel is winning? Riley?

Comment: Excel *not* wins -- See Rebol solution :-)

Answer (score 15):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>17</s> 7 bytes

```
YOd15XO
```

Input is a cell array of strings, in the form `{'1:45' '3:15'}` or `{'1:45', '3:15'}`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@x/pn2JoGuH//3@1uqGViam6grqxlaGpei0A)

#### Explanation

```
YO     % Input cell array of strings (implicit). Convert to serial date numbers
d      % Difference
15XO   % Convert to format 15, i.e. 'HH:MM'. Display (implicit)
```

Comment: Oh nice! Carry on!

Answer (score 8):

### [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils, <s>44</s>  39 bytes

```sh
tr : \ |dc -e?r60*+r-r60*-60~rn58PA~rnn
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@19SpGClEKNQk5KsoJtqX2RmoKVdpAuidM0M6oryTC0CHIFU3v//hlYmpgrGVoamAA)**

**Explanation:** using "1:45 3:15" as test case (last example). I show intermediary steps in quotes.

```sh
tr : \ |         # replace colons with spaces: "1 45 3 15"
dc -e?           # start dc script, push input to LIFO stack: "15 3 45 1"
     r60*+            # turn time B to total seconds: "195 45 1"
     r-r60*-          # turn time A to total seconds and get difference: "90"
     60~r             # turn difference (time left) to minutes and seconds: "1 30"
     n58P             # pop and print minutes, print colon (ASCII code 58): "30"
     A~rnn            # print seconds. Padding with zeroes is done by dividing by
                      #10 (A), and printing the quotient and the remainder.
```

Note that I don't check if the minute value needs zero padding, because the OP stated that the maximum value for `m` is 9.

---

Below is my original 44 bytes answer, that used the `date` command to turn the total time left in seconds to the `m:ss` format.

```sh
date -d@`tr : \ |dc -e?r60*+r-r60*-p` +%M:%S
```

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Thank you. But in the end, I managed to remove the date command and do the format printing in dc as well.

Comment: Crossed out 44 looks like regular 44.

Comment: @Riley I crossed out the spaces surrounding 44 as well, to get the effect that should have been there in the first place.

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7427/57100

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, <s>90</s> <s>87</s> <s>83</s> 80 bytes

Takes input like `"2:45","5:01"`.

```python
a,b=[60*int(s[-5:-3])+int(s[-2:])for s in input()]
print'%d:%02d'%divmod(b-a,60)
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@5@ok2QbbWaglZlXolEcrWtqpWscq6kN5RlZxWqm5RcpFCtk5gFRQWmJhmYsV0ERUFpdNcVK1cAoBUhnluXmp2gk6SbqmBlo/v@vZGRlYqqko2RqZWCoBAA)

Comment: [you can use map on input to save 3 bytes](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#LcnBCoQgEADQe18RguSU0mSrh4G@JDqMeAkqpGa/3/awx8erbNNycjEHnylz@1DEfr/EPKsL5OYNhr88bWD3q3zFADSyJMdNuX/Z6Uwafe60kTGiFR0RalWePkFZFQgn9QI)

Comment: you can use list comprehension to save several bytes: `a,b=[60*int(s[-5:-3])+int(s[-2:])for s in input()]`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can save three additional characters replacing the two last lines by `print'%d:%02d'%divmod(b-a,60)` :)

Answer (score 5):

## C, <s>112</s> 100 bytes

*Thanks to @betseg for saving 11 bytes and thanks to @Johan du Toit for saving one byte!*

```
i,j;f(char*a,char*b){i=atoi(b)-atoi(a);j=atoi(b+2)-atoi(a+2);j<0?i--,j+=60:0;printf("%d:%02d",i,j);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#XYzBCsIwEETvfkagkLUJJNV4yFr8ltRS3IC11Hgq/fa4qXrxNMN7w2RSEQd5vYV5H9QWHSzUhvQg2YHeMgDGL6mbH@OG8WwupLWKdXsy3uA005gGKareV6bpheJ3wDXfA40Slh0rnhmhSlgBOL3SUwouH@UcK1sWf8r6Y1EHb10ha34D)

Comment: You can change `%s%d` with `%02d` and remove the `?:`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#XYxBDsIgEEX3HoOkDSOQDFVcgD0MtWkcEtum4qrp2RGqbly9n/cmk0gGN/Db3S9HL3d0sFLr40S8A7XTgwtfI5qfy8uFK9Y1D6K9IAhSys0LjXHgrOpthU3PZH4PbksPTyOH9ZATWkQmCzQDN7/ik7M8PsmYnHS5@Evanks6WW2K2dIb)

Comment: [`scanf()`](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114304/11259) is your friend for reading multiple integers.

Comment: You can also save 1 byte by using: j<0?i++,j+=60:0;

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Nononono, It's usually shorter to use arguments which he did.

Answer (score 5):

## c, 86

```c
f(a,b,c,d){scanf("%d:%d%d:%d",&a,&b,&c,&d);d+=(c-a)*60-b;printf("%d:%02d",d/60,d%60);}
```

Reads space-separated times from STDIN.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#fYpBCsMgFET3nkIERdsf@m2rC6WHUT9CFg2hSVchZ7cSsu4shnkz06pOkKEAmW0paapaSAqSDhOgEqgMqoAiE@n60mVI5uJxyHH@jNN63vHev3TzCCQ9mri3vvF3Gidt2MZ4V9UmHmH@rosW4qR/9d4wIPJulmFwjtuOzIan449g3Q8).

Answer (score 5):

### Batch, 74 bytes

```
@set t=%2-(%1)
@set/as=%t::=*60+1%,m=s/60,t=s/10%%6
@echo %m%:%t%%s:~-1%
```

Replacing the `:` in the time with `*60+1` converts it into an expression that calculates the number of seconds. Batch interprets leading zeros as octal so I prepend a `1` to the seconds to ensure decimal conversion; fortunately the two `1`s cancel out.

Answer (score 5):

## MySQL, <s>13</s> 22 bytes

```sql
select right(timediff(B,A),5)
```

expects the times in `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 4):

## ECMAScript 6, <strike>99</strike> <strike>91</strike> 85 bytes

### Single Line:

```
f=s=>s.split`:`.reduce((a,e,i)=>a+e*(!i?60:1),0);t=n=>~~(n/60)+":"+n%60;t(f(b)-f(a));
```

### Slightly formatted:

```
f=s=>s.split`:`.reduce((a,e,i)=>a+e*(!i?60:1),0);
t=n=>~~(n/60)+":"+n%60;
t(f(b)-f(a));
```

I feel there could be some some savings in there.. but I am not seeing them at present.

Edit - excellent suggestions in the comments.

Comment: You can remove the parentheses around the `s`.

Comment: And instead of `s.split(":")`, you can use the newer syntax : `s.split<backtick>:<backtick>`.

Answer (score 4):

## Bash + GNU utilities, 43

```bash
date -d@`date -f- +%s|dc -e??r-60/p` +%M:%S
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#PYyxCsMgFEX3fsVFIhmKVGntYIb0Bzp1zZAQn5BFgzrm3@0rgd7hcDjDDSmjUqnrUghbhNBOazCM@Lm1MBzYjXtY3J2xYoBPF/D2vMUa0MsyxR7d/@bA1PxSCcq/5lOCwlWWw69QNI5ZPfVtnzm9nfw0nyK1Lw).

#### Explanation

```bash
         date -f- +%s                        # read in 2 line-delimited dates and output as number of seconds since the epoch
                     |dc -e                  # pipe to dc expression:
                           ??                # - read 2 input numbers
                             r-              # - reverse and subtract
                               60/           # - divide by 60
                                  p          # - output
        `                          `         # evaluate date|dc command
date -d@                             +%M:%S  # format seconds difference and output
```

Note the `dc` expression divides by 60, because `date` reads the input as H:MM instead of M:SS.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, <s>55</s> 53 bytes

```php
<?=date('i:s',($s=strtotime)($argv[2])-$s($argv[1]));
```

takes input from command line arguments

Comment: 53 bytes: `<?=date('i:s',($x=strtotime)($argv[2])-$x($argv[1]));`

Answer (score 4):

## Rebol, 5 bytes

```
b - a
```

Assuming I didn't miss any rules..

Rebol has arithmetic built-in for a number of literal data types.
This also applies to its descendants such as [Red](http://www.red-lang.org)

Comment: I know little to nothing about this language.

Comment: @carusocomputing https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol

Answer (score 3):

### C#, 72 bytes

```
using System;a=>b=>((DateTime.Parse(b)-DateTime.Parse(a))+"").Remove(5);
```

Takes input as strings.
`b="3:15"` `a="1:45"`.

#### Explanation:

Because `DateTime.Parse()` returns a Date in `hh:mm:ss` format, I am able to parse the result into a string using `+""`, then trim the trailing `:00`.

This works with `hh:mm` because there are both 60 seconds in a minute and 60 minutes in an hour.

`0:01` `0:00` returns `0:01`

`1:00` `0:55` returns  `0:05`

`3:15` `1:45` returns  `1:30`

Comment: Unfortunately, the `DateTime.Parse()` is taking the input -- for example, `1:45` -- as `hh:mm` and not `mm:ss`, resulting in the follow output -- for **A** `1:45` and **B** `3:15` -- `[01:30:00]` ( `hh:mm:ss` ) ( _even with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` specified_ ). You might have to add a `"0:" + a/b` when parsing.

Comment: @auhmaan Ah, nice catch. I ended up trimming the trailing `:00`.

Comment: I believe you need a `;` on the end, you can use currying i.e. `a=>b=>`, you need to fully qualify `DateTime` or include `using System;`.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>98</s> <s>127</s> 86 Bytes

```
r(m:_:s)=60*read[m]+read s
a#b|(d,m)<-divMod(r b-r a)60=show d++':':['0'|m<=9]++show m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@1@kkWsVb1WsaWtmoFWUmpgSnRurDaIVirkSlZNqNFJ0cjVtdFMyy3zzUzSKFJJ0ixQSNc0MbIsz8ssVUrS11a3UraLVDdRrcm1sLWO1tcHiuf9zEzPzFGwVCkpLgkuKFFQUlAytTCyVlJWMrIzMlP4DAA)

But I wonder if there are some library functions for this

EDIT: Removed import, also fixed an error where it showed m:s instead of m:ss

Also, well-formatted version:

```
convert :: String -> Integer
convert (a:_:b) = (read [a])*60+(read b)

diffTime :: String -> String -> String
diffTime s1 s2 = let (d,m) = divMod (c b-c a) 60 in show d ++ ":" ++ pad2d m

pad2d :: Int -> String
pad2d n = ['0'|n<=9]++show n
```

EDIT2: Golfed off (30?) bytes thanks to Laikoni! Also golfed some other misc. bytes.

Comment: You should tell us what language this is and how many bytes it uses.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mean to press post (who knew tab+enter from the text box posts your answer?)

Comment: Same approach, 86 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@1@kkWsVb1WsaWtmoFWUmpgSnRurDaIVirkSlZNqNFJ0cjVtdFMyy3zzUzSKFJJ0ixQSNc0MbIsz8ssVUrS1layUtLWj1Q3Ua3JtLGO1tcHiuf9zEzPzFGwVCkpLgkuKFFQUlAysDE2UlJWMrAxNlf4DAA "Haskell – TIO Nexus")

Comment: I didn't think of using a list comprehension. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>47</s> <s>45</s> <s>44</s> 40 Bytes

```
J.U-Zbm+*60hdedmmvkcd\:.z%"%d:%02d".DJ60
```

Takes the input separated by newlines.

Pyth had no time built-ins useful for this. I tried some fancy eval() stuff but apparantly Pyth can't eval stuff with `*` or any leading zeroes whatsoever. This got much longer than i hoped. Quite some bytes are spent on adding a leading zero to the output. At least I'm shorter than bash. Will add explanation if asked.

[Try this!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J.U-Zbm%2B%2a60hdedmmvkcd%5C%3A.z%25%22%25d%3A%2502d%22.DJ60&input=1%3A45%0A2%3A05&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%3A00%0A0%3A01%0A0%3A55%0A1%3A00%0A1%3A45%0A3%3A15&debug=0&input_size=2)

#### alternative solution, 48 Bytes

```
J.U-Zbm+*60hdh_dmmvkcd\:.z
K%J60
s[/J60\:*<KT\0K
```

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, 238 bytes

```
CREATE PROCEDURE d @a time,@b time AS BEGIN DECLARE @d int DECLARE @s varchar(2) SET @d=datediff(s,@a,@b);SET @s=CAST(@d%3600/60 AS VARCHAR(3)) SELECT CAST(@d/3600 AS VARCHAR(3))+':'+(SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(@s)=1 THEN '0'+@s ELSE @s END)END
```

Usage:

```
EXEC d '00:55','01:00'
```

Seeing the PostGres example earlier I realised I hadn't seen many golfing attempts in SQL so I had a go at it in T-SQL. Now I know *why* you don't see much golfing in SQL :D

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>34</s> <s>33</s> 25 bytes

*Saved 8 bytes thanks to Martin Ender!*

```
{r':/60b}2*\m60mds2Te[':\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@19dpG6lb2aQVGukFZNrZpCbUmwUkhqtbhXz/7@hlYmpgrGVoSkA)

**Explanation**

```
{             e# Start of block
 r            e#  Read one time from input
 ':/          e#  Split on colons, gives [minutes seconds]
 60b          e#  Convert from base 60
}2*           e# Run this block 2 times
              e# At this point, we have the two times in seconds on the stack
\             e# Swap top elements
m             e# Subtract
60md          e# Divmod the result by 60, to convert back to minutes and seconds
s             e# Convert the seconds to a string
2Te[          e# Pad it to 2 characters by adding 0s to the left (T = 0)
':            e# Push a colon character
\             e# Swap top elements, bringing seconds back to the top
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 160 bytes

I am still new to code golf so if anyone has any suggestions, I would appreciate it.

```python
a, b = input()
def z(x):
    x = x.split(":")
    return int(x[0])*60+int(x[1])
a, b = z(a),z(b)
s, m = b-a,0
while s >= 60:
    s -= 60
    m += 1
print(str(m)+":"+str(s))
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to our site.  It seems that you are taking input for your program from preinitialized variables.  However this is not permitted under out [defaults for IO](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).  I would recommend for this specific case to take input via `raw_input()`.

Answer (score 2):

### T-SQL, 82 Bytes

```
select left(cast(dateadd(minute, datediff(S,'0:00','0:01')/60,114) as time(0)), 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

### REXX, 79 bytes

```
arg t q
say right(time(,f(q)-f(t),s),5)
f:return time(s,'00:'right(arg(1),5,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 28

```
%"%d:%02d".Dh.+misMcd\:60Q60
```

[Try it](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%25%22%25d%3A%2502d%22.Dh.%2BmisMcd%5C%3A60Q60&input=%5B%220%3A00%22%2C%20%220%3A01%22%5D%0A%5B%220%3A55%22%2C%20%221%3A00%22%5D%0A%5B%221%3A45%22%2C%20%223%3A15%22%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%220%3A00%22%2C%20%220%3A01%22%5D%0A%5B%220%3A55%22%2C%20%221%3A00%22%5D%0A%5B%221%3A45%22%2C%20%223%3A15%22%5D&debug=0).

#### Explanation

```
                   cd\:      # lambda to split c on ":"
                 sM          # map to convert string to int
               mi      60Q   # convert from base-60 list to give seconds
             .+              # delta of the two seconds values
            h                # single-item list to int
          .D              60 # divmod by 60
%"%d:%02d"                   # format output
```

Answer (score 1):

## TXR Lisp, 101 bytes

```
$ txr -e '(awk (:let (s "%M:%S"))
               ((mf (time-parse s))
                (prn (time-string-local (- [f 1].(time-utc) [f 0].(time-utc)) s))))'
13:49 14:49 
01:00
0:13 1:47
01:34
5:01 5:59
00:58
6:00 6:00
00:00
6:00 5:00
59:00
```

Condensed: `(awk(:let(s"%M:%S"))((mf(time-parse s))(prn(time-string-local(-[f 1].(time-utc)[f 0].(time-utc))s))))`

Comment: You need a bytecount, and I don't think this is fully golfed.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, 164 bytes

```
String c(String a,String b){long s=x(b,1)-x(a,1)+(x(b,0)-x(a,0))*60,m=s%60;return(s/60)+":"+(m>9?m:"0"+m);}long x(String s,int i){return new Long(s.split(":")[i]);}
```

**Explanation:**

```
String c(String a, String b){       // Method with two String parameters and String return-type
  long s = x(b,1) - x(a,1)          //  Get difference in seconds from input times
           + (x(b,0) - x(a,0)*60,   //   plus the difference in minutes times 60 to get the seconds
    m = s%60;                       //  Temp variable of seconds after we've subtracted the minutes (used multiple times)
  return (s/60)                     //  Return minutes
    +":"                            //   plus ":"
    +(m>9?m:"0"+m);                 //   plus seconds (with a leading 0 if necessary)
}                                   // End of method

long x(String s,int i){             // Separate ethod with String and Integer parameters and long return-type
  return new Long(s.split(":")[i];  //  Return either minutes or seconds of String parameter based on the index
}                                   // End of method
```

**Test code:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#hY1Ba4QwEIXv@yuGQGGmujbSKlSx/QP1tMdlD9GVEkiimLi1iL/dRteedy5v3vC9N7US1kI5LSfXS/MNNe6LCPelokm1Xm0xYhXGdBxReAlwtfxuOdFzykNd2KeU533jht6gfUk5BSxjAeqP90@dMc4CTfm81Y3/j2wojQNJ0z0GpvmBL0@gjWynpEPfQGd58cEFoBsqJWuwTjgvt1ZeQQtp9rLzBQRNB/BTgoZiKyuR8u10@rWu0VE7uKjztFMGdVQj4xnnLIRVY0YP4SRZ4XgNPYLj7G2DX7M42eH5MC9/)

```
class M{
  String c(String a,String b){long s=x(b,1)-x(a,1)+(x(b,0)-x(a,0))*60,m=s%60;return(s/60)+":"+(m>9?m:"0"+m);}long x(String s,int i){return new Long(s.split(":")[i]);}

  public static void main(String[] a){
    M m = new M();
    System.out.println(m.c("0:00", "0:01"));
    System.out.println(m.c("0:55", "1:00"));
    System.out.println(m.c("1:45", "3:15"));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0:01
0:05
1:30
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 91 bytes

```ruby
require'time';t=Time;d=t.parse($*[1])-t.parse($*[0]);puts t.at(d.to_i).utc.strftime '%H:%M'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#@1@UWliaWZSqXpKZm6puXWIbAqStU2xL9AoSi4pTNVS0og1jNXWRuAaxmtYFpSXFCiV6iSUaKXol@fGZmnqlJcl6xSVFaSBjFNRVPaxUfdX///9vaGVi@t/YytAUAA)

Takes input from command line arguments.

#### Invocation:

```ruby
ruby outatime.rb $A $B
```

#### Example:

```ruby
ruby outatime.rb 1:45 3:15
```

Output:

> 01:30

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell 47 Bytes

```cs
param($s,[timespan]$f)($f-$s).ToString("h\:mm")
```

Simple timespan math and coverting to hour and seconds string.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 88 bytes

```javascript
a=>b=>{c=a.split`:`,d=b.split`:`;return +c[0]-d[0]-d[1]>c[1]?1:0+":"+(+c[1]+60-d[1])%60}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#S7P9n2hrl2RrV51sm6hXXJCTWZJglaCTYpsE51gXpZaUFuUpaCdHG8TqpkAIw1i7ZCBhb2hloK1kpaStoQ3iapsZgOU0Vc0Mav8n5@cV5@ek6uXkp2ukaSgZWhkbKGlqKBlYGZsqaWr@BwA)

### Explanation:

Splits the inputs on the colon

```javascript
c=a.split`:`,d=b.split`:`;
```

Converts string to int

```javascript
+c[0]
```

Gets the minute value

```javascript
+c[0]-d[0]-d[1]>c[1]?1:0
```

Gets the second value

```javascript
(+c[1]+60-d[1])%60
```

Returns the string minutes:seconds

```javascript
return +c[0]-d[0]-d[1]>c[1]?1:0+":"+(+c[1]+60-d[1])%60
```